# What is the use of CommandType.StoredProcedure in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am executing the following code:-

```
try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VGDB"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("abc", sqlConn);
                    cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return -1;
            }
```

I am executing a stored procedure with no parameter. My sp just returns 0 or 1. Now my question is what is the use of:-

```
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

because my code also runs correctly without this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

The commandType StoredProcudere adds EXEC instruction before you stored procedure name:
ex:

```
EXEC abc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know is it necessary to add this line of code. When my code is also running without this line then why I will add this line. Please explain in detail.